# Chrome renders extremely simple page differently through the local file path, than through HTTP

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, simplehttpserver

If I open a HTML page locally (i.e, by double-clicking it in the Mac's Finder),  it renders  very differently compared to accessing it through HTTP.

For a minimal example:
[image: Screenshot]

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="ok" />
  </body>
</html>
```

The local file path looks like this:
[image: Local version]

But when the page is served through a server, it looks like this:
[image: remote version]

Remotely, I have tried three different HTTP servers:  Apache, Flask and Python's SimpleHTTPServer.  Chrome has an issue with all of them.  Safari does not have this issue.

Comment: You mean the same browser has different button style between "local" and "remote" site?

Comment: Yes. The file looks differently if open it by "double-clicking it", or if I go to the remote url.

Comment: "remotely" means you deploy application to not local server? Can you link the remote site?

Comment: @JoseG try to check the file path where the page looks for CSS files

Comment: Look at the minimal example I built, no CSS.  @DineiRockenbach

Comment: @JoseG Can you inspect button element by chrome dev tools? See the "Styles" tab  and compare "user agent stylesheet" values between local and remote.

Comment: @JoseG And tell your chrome version might be helpful.

Comment: @sayingu  I'm using the latest version (Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit))

And Eureka! The user-agent stylesheets look different (it has hundreds of lines), but the local "body" has  margin, while the remote doesn't.   Any thought about this?   Is this a bug?

Comment: @DineiRockenbach Unhelpful comment. I just edit the post with evidence that this is not user error.

Comment: @JoseG Just tried to help on figuring out the issue... It still makes no sense to me.

Comment: @DineiRockenbach It does not make sense to me either, but as-per sayingu 's suggestion, it seems to be related to "user agent stylesheets" applied differently when served through http than through file.  Not sure how to fix it, though! :)

Comment: Did you come up with any understanding of the cause of this? I've had a few similar issues: https://gitlab.pagedmedia.org/tools/pagedjs/issues/340 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62380128/css-background-image-repeats-not-playing-nicely-with-python-http-server-and-chro

Answer (score 1):

Add "doctype" top of the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The way it looks is not depends on what server side programming you use or whats happening on your server. maybe there is some additional `CSS` or caching things.

try clear your browser's cache and check it again.

Comment: There's no server-side programming on this example.  Did you see the code I added?

Comment: @JoseG but you're talking about `Flask and Python's SimpleHTTPServer` in the question. Both are server-side related.

Comment: To avoid red herrings, I created a minimal example that does not have server-side programming, nor CSS.   It's just a 4 line HTML file.

Comment: sorry i misunderstood, why should you open a HTML file with browser directly to test it.if you want to test the product test it in real environment!

Comment: @JoseG All those stuff is needed and affecting BTW, like you can add inline style with serverside programming or somehow u r using the path to files that simply not available in that way. it could be anything.

Comment: @JoseG i can't comment on other's post, just to mention you can use `reset.css` or things like that which reset every lets say assumption that browsers have. i think it's the most accurate way to do this. check [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you have the same version of Chrome for local and remote?

Comment: Yes, I'm only using my laptop.

Comment: You mean, you are accessing your laptop remotely?

Comment: Yes. I started both SimpleHTTPServer, and flask, to serve the file. I went to localhost:80/test.html   and the file looks differently than if I just double click it!!!

Comment: I am not sure but I think it is something with how SimpleHTTPServer and Flask renders the remote views, it has nothing to do with the browser. Can you try TeamViewer instead.

Comment: I just tried with Apache as well, and it still renders differently. I can't use TeamViewer because I'm on Mac. 

But it's three servers that work differently :)